# error: incomplete chunked encoding in php scripts

Tags: php, http

Trying to run some php scripts on a new shared server account, the scripts constantly hang and timeout with no error messages. Only when running the scripts in Chrome with the web developer console up did I get a hint of what was going on: "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" is what it would say.

Fiddler2 was slightly more specific:

Fiddler.Network.ProtocolViolation - [#165] Transfer-Encoding: Chunked response did not terminate with a proper zero-size chunk.

...and:

Fiddler.Network.ProtocolViolation - [#165] [HTTPLint #M012] The HTTP Chunked response body was incomplete; most likely lacking the final 0-size chunk.

I made a test script to demonstrate the problem. All it did was sleep() for a random 20-60 seconds, then display a random string. Ten iterations by default.

But the helpdesk at this hosting provider kept insisting that it had something to do with a hard 60 second timeout in the php environment, which I knew was hogwash. So I put together a second test script that used Ajax to call another script multiple times in succession. Again, it was bone simple, just a sleep() for a random time between 40 and 55 seconds, then generate and display a short random string of characters.

So it could never take more than 60 seconds to execute. But it still kept failing, albeit with "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" for the xhr call in the Chrome console instead of "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING".

When I showed this to them, they actually admitted there was a problem, which felt like a victory. But it was short-lived. The very next day they came back and said, so sorry, they couldn't figure out what was causing this, nothing they can do, have I considered upgrading to a vps?

I have become somewhat obsessed. I want to know what the hell is causing this.

The code for the first test script I wrote:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(3600);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

isset($_REQUEST["limit"]) ? $limit = $_REQUEST["limit"] : $limit = 10;



echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">';

echo "<title>Test Script</title></head><body>";

//ob_start ();
echo "<br><br>A random delay between 20 and 60 seconds will be generated, then a randomly generated string will be displayed<br>The default limit on iterations is ten<br>When the script terminates normally, the phrase \"test complete\" will be output at the bottom<br><br>";
 flush();


for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
  $delay = mt_rand (20, 60);
  echo "<br><br><br>iteration ".($i+1)." - script will now sleep for $delay seconds";
    flush();
  sleep ($delay);
  echo "<br><br>Here is a random string:<br>";
  $length = mt_rand (50, 100);
  echo generateRandomString($length);
    flush();
} 


echo '<br><br>...test complete</body></html>';
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

You can go to this page: http://www.scripttest1.cu.cc/test_script.php to see for yourself what happens when it is run on this server.

The code for the second test script:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(600);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

isset($_REQUEST["limit"]) ? $limit = $_REQUEST["limit"] : $limit = 15;
isset($_REQUEST["longorshort"]) ? $longorshort = $_REQUEST["longorshort"] : $longorshort = "long";
$start = 1;

echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">';

echo "<title>Test Script 2</title></head><body>";
echo '<script src="test_script_js7.js"></script>';

echo "
  <br>Clicking the button below will start the script running
  <br>The script called via XMLHttpRequest will generate a random delay between 40 and 55 seconds (5-10 seconds if \"longorshort\" is set to \"short\" in the url string), then a randomly generated string will be displayed in the table on the bottom
  <br>The default limit on iterations is fifteen
  <br>When the process terminates normally, the phrase \"test complete\" will be output in the \"Main Info\" cell
  <br><b>The script called via XMLHttpRequest will <u>never take more than 60 seconds</u> to complete processing</b>

";
//echo "<img src=http://nzbstar.info/download_batch.png onclick=\"getter($limit, '$start', '$longorshort')\"><br>";
echo "<br><img src=start.jpg onclick=\"getter_outer($limit, '$start', '$longorshort')\"><br><a href=\"javascript:master_switch();\">click here to abort</a>  ";

echo "<table border=1><tr>";
echo "<td valign=top><div id=main_info>Main Info:</div></td>";
echo "<td valign=top><div id=iteration>Iterations:</div></td>";
echo "<td valign=top><div id=message>Messages:</div></td>";
echo "</tr></table>";

echo "<table border=1 style=table-layout:fixed;><tr>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
  echo "<td valign=top><div class=getter id=post_$i><i>Result $i</i></div></td>";
  if ( ($i%5 == 0) ) {echo "</tr><tr>";}
}
echo "</tr></table>";




echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

...the javascript:

```
var master_off = false;
var getter_running_now = false;

function getter_outer(limit, i, longorshort){
  if (getter_running_now) {alert ("Script is already running!"); return;}
  getter_running_now = true;

  if (master_off) {document.getElementById("main_info").innerHTML += "<br>master switch off, aborting!"; return;} 
  if (i >= limit) {document.getElementById("main_info").innerHTML += "<br>Got to the next getter when we shouldn't have, there's a bug!"; return;}
  getter(limit, i, longorshort);
}

function getter(limit, i, longorshort){  
  if (master_off) {document.getElementById("main_info").innerHTML += "<br>master switch off, aborting!"; return;} 
  if (i >= limit) {document.getElementById("main_info").innerHTML += "<br>Got to the next getter when we shouldn't have, there's a bug!"; return;}

  var post_number_element = "post_" + i;

  var batch_result_script = "test_script_2a.php?longorshort=" + longorshort;

  document.getElementById("iteration").innerHTML = "Iterations:<br>Doing iteration: " + i;
  document.getElementById(post_number_element).innerHTML = "doing this one...<br>";
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
      if (xmlhttp.status==200){
        var result = "<b>result for " + post_number_element + " is:</b><br>" + xmlhttp.responseText + "<br><span style=color:green;>Success!</span>";
        document.getElementById(post_number_element).innerHTML = result;
        i++;
        if (i >= limit) {
          document.getElementById("main_info").innerHTML += "<br><span style=color:green;>Test complete!</span>";
        }
        else {getter(limit, i, longorshort);}
      }
      else {document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<br> - <span style=color:red;>http return status for iteration " + i + " was " + xmlhttp.status + "</span>";}
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",batch_result_script,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}



function master_switch(){
  master_off = true;
  document.getElementById("main_info").innerHTML += "<br><span style=color:red;>Master Switch Off!</span>";
```

}

...and the script it calls via ajax:

```
 <?php
set_time_limit(600);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

if ( isset($_REQUEST["longorshort"]) && $_REQUEST["longorshort"] == "short" ) {$delay = mt_rand (5, 10);}
else {$delay = mt_rand (40, 55);}


sleep ($delay);
echo "<br>Here is a random string:<br>";
$length = mt_rand (5, 10);
echo generateRandomString($length);


?>
```

Go here: http://www.scripttest1.cu.cc/test_script_2.php?longorshort=long to see it in action. Unlike with the first script, the error it generates is "empty response". But I assume the two are related.

Both these scripts work fine on both another shared server, and a vps with LAMP, to which I have access. They also work on *this* server, for a while, before they fail. The first test script usually gets through a few iterations before it dies. The second one, with the Ajax, will *sometimes* run right through to completion if the "longorshort" is set to "short".

Also, the first test script works flawlessly from the command line. The second one of course won't work right in that environment.

The server runs PHP Version 5.4.44 and Apache Version 2.4.16 under Linux.

Google has not been my friend. I posted to Stackoverflow and got exactly 5 (five) views, zero responses.

Can anyone here at least toss me a clue? Or failing that, point me to an alternative to Stackoverflow where they might actually answer my question?

Comment: Make your server answer HTTP 1.0, with a string like that nokeepalive force-response-1.0 downgrade-1.0. Chunked Encoding was introduced In HTTP1.1. A big side note, it's a plaster to patch a big error in your script, but I'am not a script expert, thus offer the plaster. (As with chunked encoding the server send in a more "streamed" way the data to save on bandwidth (with less header) and to save on active connection open)

Comment: Wow, 2 days on Stackoverflow with no answer, 20 minutes here and something has already popped up.    Thank you for your answer. I had considered doing that, but it's sort of burning down the village to save it.  I really need to be able to see the output as it is generated, and scripts that run a long time with no response tend to timeout with just a blank page in my experience.

Comment: Do a wireshark then, it's traffic easy to follow up. You will see each packet will start with chunk size after the http header, in the data, and it finish with 0.

Comment: Ok, Wireshark was very intimidating, and my knowledge of tcp is sparse to say the least. But I got it installed and running and myself up to a point where I half-way know what I'm doing, kinda.

I am still not sure what's going on, but I am guessing that this "incomplete chunked encoding" business was a mis-interpretaion by Chrome and Fiddler.

It is not the output from the script that is causing the timeout. Rather, I will see a packet labelled, "[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]", that contains the script output.

Comment: For clarity in your windows, do a ip.src==local ip && ip.dst==remote_ip

Comment: (cont) It will say (for example), "script will now sleep for 58 seconds" (that's the random delay). Then, 27 seconds later (or some seconds that is less than the delay), I will see a sequence of 4 packets, one right after the other. The first has [FIN, ACK] server to client. Then [ACK] client to server, then [FIN, ACK] client to server. Then [ACK] server to client.

And right about at the same time, the "incomplete chunked encoding" error shows up in the Chrome console. Except it logically can't be that, because the script isn't sending anything right then, it hasn't finished the random delay.

Comment: (cont)So, for some reason the server is sending this "finished" signal, causing the script to timeout, which looks to Chrome like "incomplete chunked encoding".

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @ yagmoth555 I did ip.dst == remote ip or ip.src == remote ip

Comment: Any difference if you use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` rather than "TRUE"? Anything in your server error log?

Comment: @Matt Gibson regarding the error log, when I was wrangling with the helpdesk they told me there were no errors in it. It's a shared server so I can't access it directly. As the the ini_set change, I can't tell if that makes a difference because the server's behavior has changed. Now all I get is a blank page and an "empty response" error. I can log on to the shell and see that the script continues for some time after that, but nothing is getting back to me. What the hell is up with this server?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer with your wireshark info, as with all delay wrote like that, the 58sec delay bugged me.

When Internet Explorer establishes a persistent HTTP connection with a Web server (by using Connection: Keep-Alive headers), Internet Explorer reuses the same TCP/IP socket that was used to receive the initial request until the socket is idle for one minute. **After the connection is idle for one minute, Internet Explorer resets the connection**. A new TCP/IP socket is used to receive additional requests. You may want to change the HTTP KeepAliveTimeout value in Internet Explorer.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813827

That let me think other browser must follow that standard, so you must send something on the line when you script run to prevent closing the connection, as you can't ask your customers to change their timeout value.

Comment: I don't think that's it. Timeouts occur after well under 60 seconds of idleness. And the exact same script runs fine at a couple of other sites where I was able to upload it, in the same browser. No, it must have something to do with the host...

Comment: @MackManhattan In worst case try it, it's two registry item in the KB to edit

Comment: @ yagmoth555 ok I tried it, no effect unfortunately.